# sql文が理解できない

Tags: java, sql

```
    sectionQuery
        .append("SELECT a.classNo").append(multiLang ? ", b.classNo target_lang_no" : "")
        .append(" FROM ").append(getSTName(SorL, "goods")).append(" a ");
```

Javaの構文をなくして、sqlのみでみているのですが、？の意味など下記がどのようなクエリなのかわかりません。
下記はsql以外にもほかの言語が入っていますでしょうか？

SELECT a.classNo　multiLang ? , b.classNo target_lang_no : ""　
　　　　　FROM getSTName(SorL, "goods")　a；

上記のクエリの処理内容を知りたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

文中の以下の部分はJavaの3項演算子による計算を行っているので、変数`multiLang`が`true`か`false`で内容が変化します。

```
multiLang ? ", b.classNo target_lang_no" : ""
```

- `true`の場合:

  `, b.classNo target_lang_no`になる
- `false`の場合:

  空文字になる

また、`getTSName(SorL, "goods")`の箇所はJavaのメソッド呼び出しと思います。(具体的処理は質問文からは想定できませんが、テーブル名を取得するメソッドではないかと思います)

ですので、生成されるSQL文は次のいずれかのパターンになると思います。

- `SELECT SELECT a.classNo, b.classNo target_lang_no FROM (テーブル名) a`
- `SELECT SELECT a.classNo FROM (テーブル名) a`

＃前者のパターンの場合、テーブル`b`が足らないので、`getTSName`メソッドは複数のテーブル名を取得するメソッド化も知れません。